# Stream sound file to an asterisk user?

Tags: php, asterisk

I’m trying to stream a sound file (.wave) to an asterisk (sip) user or to a user set.

Do you have any ideas?

thank you in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! What did you try so far? Any code examples?

Answer (score 1):

Sound file should be in EXACT format bellow for uncompressed files

```
pcm uncompressed 8khz mono
```

Any other format will be skipped.

Also you should not include file extension in command, asterisk will select most suitable file(can be more then 1 format with same name and different extensions, for example file.g729 in g729 codec).

For start play system file, for example "beep".

Any asterisk book have examples and description how to do that. Can recommend ORelly's "Asterisk The Future of Telephony" book.